# How can I switch between rendering modes of standard shader?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The shader:

```
Shader "Standard"
{
    Properties
    {
        [LM_Albedo] [LM_Transparency] _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)  
        [LM_MasterTilingOffset] [LM_Albedo] _MainTex("Albedo", 2D) = "white" {}

        [LM_TransparencyCutOff] _AlphaTestRef("Alpha Cutoff", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.5

        [LM_Glossiness] _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.0
        [LM_Metallic] _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.0
        [LM_Metallic] [LM_Glossiness] _MetallicGlossMap("Metallic", 2D) = "white" {}

        _BumpScale("Scale", Float) = 1.0
        [LM_NormalMap] _BumpMap("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}

        _Parallax ("Height Scale", Range (0.005, 0.08)) = 0.02
        _ParallaxMap ("Height Map", 2D) = "black" {}

        _OcclusionStrength("Strength", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 1.0
        _OcclusionMap("Occlusion", 2D) = "white" {}

        [LM_Emission] _EmissionColor("Color", Color) = (0,0,0)
        [LM_Emission] _EmissionMap("Emission", 2D) = "white" {}

        _DetailMask("Detail Mask", 2D) = "white" {}

        _DetailAlbedoMap("Detail Albedo x2", 2D) = "grey" {}
        _DetailNormalMapScale("Scale", Float) = 1.0
        _DetailNormalMap("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}

        [KeywordEnum(UV1, UV2)] _UVSec ("UV Set for secondary textures", Float) = 0

        // UI-only data
        [KeywordEnum(None, Realtime, Baked)]  _Lightmapping ("GI", Int) = 1
        [HideInInspector] _EmissionScaleUI("Scale", Float) = 1.0
        [HideInInspector] _EmissionColorUI("Color", Color) = (0,0,0)
        [HideInInspector] _EmissionColorWithMapUI("Color", Color) = (1,1,1)

        // Blending state
        [HideInInspector] _Mode ("__mode", Float) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _SrcBlend ("__src", Float) = 1.0
        [HideInInspector] _DstBlend ("__dst", Float) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _ZWrite ("__zw", Float) = 1.0
    }
```

It have 4 modes: Opaque, Cutout, Fade, Transparent
I want to switch between this 4 modes and affecting the specific gameobject shader rendering modes in the hierarchy using a button.

Each click on the button will switch to the next mode.

And in EditorWindow

The script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeShaderRenderingModes : EditorWindow
{
    public enum BlendMode
    {
        Opaque,
        Cutout,
        Fade,
        Transparent
    }

    [MenuItem("Tools/Change Rendering Modes")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<ChangeShaderRenderingModes>("ChangeRenderingModes");
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(50,50,50,50), "Switch Mode"))
        {
            var objects = Selection.objects;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to make the switching and accessing the shader parameters.